# Submit app to App Store, storyboard contains invalid file name

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Im getting this explanation when my app is rejected by Apple:

> Invalid File Name - Your package contains a file 'XXXX.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc/.nib' with a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names. Also avoid leading or trailing whitespace characters in the file names.

What is this .nib file and how do i resolve this error?

I did `cd` into the `MainStoryboard.storyboardc` folder and there was a file `?.nib`, but when i press `cat <tab>` i have to type `^V.nib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding my entire story-board. Thankfully i had my classes intact so it only took about 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that @PPCC's answer worked. I had some trouble finding the folder though so I want to share that here. The easiest I think to find it is to go to the derived data for your project. In Xcode, go to Window->Projects and then you can see where the derived data resides for your project.

So my .nib file was located in /Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/.app/.storyboardc

There I found a file with name "??.nib". I used the "cat" command to open it in command line and then scanned the information in there for the viewcontroller that the .nib file belonged to. I then deleted that viewcontroller from the storyboard and created it again. I made sure to specify a storyboard id. Then I cleaned the project and rebuilt it. It didn't create that .nib file again and I had no problems afterward.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I didn't want to remake all the storyboard file again because it was very hard.

Finally I solved it like below:

The problem was there was a file named ".nib" inside a directory that is automatically created "myAppName.app/MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboardc".
It's supposed that, when compiling the app, this directory is automatically created and inside there, a lot of files are created related to all the views included inside my storyboard.

The file ".nib" is difficult to find because the MacOs thinks it's a hidden file because it starts with a point.

After being able to open the .nib file I saw it was like an xml file and I recognized the storyboard identifier of one of my views that where on my storyboard.

After that I delete the .nib file and I delete the view inside my storyboard as well. After re-compiling the app the file .nib wasn't created.

So, I added another view to my storyboard and re-designed it like it previously was, and put the same storyboard identifier as well. Only one view.

After that the app compiled well, the .nib file wasn't created, and the app has passed the Apple first revision (now it's waiting for review).

So, there's a bug, maybe in XCode, that creates a .nib file of some storyboard views by error.

I hope this could help in the future if someone has the same problem.

Comment: Where this file is located?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I might have solved mine by removing 'compile with bitcode' option. Further testing required

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to all the other answers: In my case there was a 'storyboardIdentifier' in the storyboard file with a newline. Removing this identifier fixed the problem.